# Appxbundle for universal apps

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a way to create an appxbundle that would contain both Windows Phone and Windows RT/8.1 packages?

I only get the 'Create Packages...' option if I right click a distinct phone/Windows project in my Universal solution, not on the solution or Shared component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You also would not be able to upload such a "multi-bundle" to the Windows Store - or at least you would have to upload it twice anyway.

I am curious, though - why would you want to do that?

Comment: this had nothing to do with the store, there are other methods of app distribution. Unfortunately, i also found out from MSDN that MS currently don't support this.